# Any way to select a line of text in browser screen by webdriver to emulate keyboard or mouse?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I want to use WebDriver to select a line of text in browser screen(actually in CKEditor editing area) then change its text style from CKEditor toolbar. Any method can do that?

For example, a line with html code like below:

this is a sample line.

I try to use Actions to build a mouse action chain but no success due to not familiar with that. Thanks for any hints or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is actually possible with WebDriver. What you would want to do is to `clickAndHold(...).moveByOffset(...).release(...)`. Unforunately, WebDriver only allows a `WebElement` as a parameter to `clickAndHold()`.

My best advice to you is to emulate JavaScript events for this. You can then do something like this in your test:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(...);
```

I wrote code for emulating mouse events which I use with some of my Selenium tests. Although it doesn't do exactly what you want, hopefully it will be useful (hopefully you can just set the x/y coords and perhaps that will get it working):

```
var f = function() {
  var id  = "ext-gen1116";
  var top = document.querySelector( '#ext-gen1116:nthchild(0)' );
  var bot = document.getElementById( id ).childNodes[3];

  var getX = function( obj ) {
    if( obj == null ) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return obj.offsetLeft + getX( obj.offsetParent );
    }
  }

  var getY = function( obj ) {
    if( obj == null ) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return obj.offsetTop + getY( obj.offsetParent );
    }
  }

  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  bot.dispatchEvent(evt);

  evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("mousemove", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, getX( top ) - getX( bot ), getY( top ) - getY( bot ),
    false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  bot.dispatchEvent(evt);

  var mouseup = function( elem ) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("mouseup", true, true, window,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }

  setTimeout( mouseup, 500, bot );
};
f();
```

If it's possible for you to do what you want with the keyboard instead, this is by far the better solution. You can simply do `driver.sendKeys(...)`. The [Keys](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html) enum will be priceless for you in this case :-)

Comment: Thanks Mike. Got js work from google for my case. post link below for reference.  http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/5f0bf177ddbb199d

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to do it with JavaScript:

```js
let el = document.querySelectorAll("p")[0];
let range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(el);
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
```